# draw line between 2 points in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

I want to draw line between 2 points. But UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() is return null

ViewController.m

```
self.drawLine.firstPoint = self.btnPointOne.bounds.origin;
self.drawLine.secondPoint = self.btnPointTwo.bounds.origin;
[self.drawLine drawRect:self.drawWatchModeView.bounds];
```

DrawLine.h

```
@interface DrawLine : UIView{
    CGContextRef context;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint firstPoint;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint secondPoint;
```

DrawLine.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Drawing code
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    //line width
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.firstPoint.x, self.firstPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.secondPoint.x, self.secondPoint.y);
    // and now draw the Path!
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

But it error

> CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

I try to `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set `YES` it not work for me
I try to remove `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` it not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just call `drawRect:` whenever you want, so your line:

```
[self.drawLine drawRect:self.drawWatchModeView.bounds];
```

needs to change to ask the OS to run a draw cycle. When that happens the drawing context will be setup and everything will be ready. When you run it explicitly that context doesn't exist. So, change that line to:

```
[self.drawLine setNeedsDisplay];
```

or

```
[self.drawLine setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.drawWatchModeView.bounds];
```